# python pandas read text file as csv skipping lines at the beginning and at the end

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a text file that that I would like to load into a pandas DF.
looks like this:

```
SESS  UID       DBASE                 TYPE  TRANS____  ELAPSE______  RESP________  CPU__________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000  ALLUSERS  PARIS                 0107        753       235.717       235.712     158.995343
0000  ALLUSERS  NewYork               0107         15         3.262         3.262       1.292182
... # thousands of lines 
0000 SEP
```

following some answers of SO I am using:

```
f = pd.read_csv("DATA/e201910.txt", skiprows=2, header=None, delimiter=r"\s+" )
```

but it does not work.

The error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 327684, saw 8
```

It looks like the last line causes problems.
How can I skip the last line together with the first two lines?

thanks

Comment: A recent version of pandas should read the file correctly, which version did you use?

Comment: If it's not a versioning thing, then maybe try parsing to a list of dicts as an intermediate step, which will allow you more control to edit out invalid rows, and then dataframe.from_dict?